# How to add for loop into data table add new row

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am trying to add a for loop that will display out a list of items on my dropdown box. However i am unsure of how i can insert it into my datatable.fnAddData.

```
var oTable;

$(document).ready(function () {

oTable = $('#TempTable6').dataTable({
    responsive: true
});

$("#addNew").click(function (e) {
    var rowCount = $('.exercise-records').length;
    var html = '<tr style="border:1px solid black" class="exercise-records"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + (rowCount + 1) + '&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>'
    $.ajax({
        url: "/AssignExercisesViewModel/InitialiseExercises",
        datatype: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (result) {

         oTable.fnAddData([
          '<tr style="border:1px solid black" class="exercise-records"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + (rowCount + 1) + '&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>',
             '<td><select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ExerciseRegionID must be a number." id=ddlRegion' + rowCount + ' name=[' + rowCount + '].ExerciseRegionID><option value="">Select an Exercise Region</option>' +
                'for (var i = 0; i < '+ result.data.length +'; i++) {' +
                   '<option value= ' +result.data[i].Value +'>' +  result.data[i]+'         </option>' +
                 '}'
            //more columns with additional  information
         ]);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();    
});
}
```

The codes above are the codes that are related to adding of new rows, as you can see i have already inserted the for loop. However there are errors when i run this for loop, i am unsure of how i should write it to allow it to read it as a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it as a string first before putting it inside the `oTable.fnAddData` array

```
var tblRow = '<tr style="border:1px solid black" class="exercise-records">';
    tblROw += '<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + (rowCount + 1) + '&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
    tblROw += '<td><select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ExerciseRegionID must be a number." id=ddlRegion' + rowCount + ' name=[' + rowCount + '].ExerciseRegionID><option value="">Select an Exercise Region</option>';

for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length ; i++) {
    tblRow += '<option value= ' +result.data[i].Value +'>' + result.data[i]+'</option>';
}

tblRow += '</select>';
tblRow += '</td>';
tblRow += '</tr>';
```

And add`tblRow` inside `oTable.fnAddData`

```
oTable.fnAddData([ 
    tblRow       
    //more columns with additional  information
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Will try this method

Answer (score 1):

Try using `each` and build the option list first and use `row.add` to add a new row to the datatable

```
var option =  [];

    $.each(result.data,function(i,v) {
      option.push('<option value= "' +v.Value +'">'+v+'</option>')
    }

        oTable.row.add(['<tr style="border:1px solid black" class="exercise-records"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + (rowCount + 1) + '&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ExerciseRegionID must be a number." id=ddlRegion' + rowCount + ' name=[' + rowCount + '].ExerciseRegionID><option value="">Select an Exercise Region</option>' + option +'</select>//more columns with additional  information']);
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, will try this method. :D